# How to create an async web service using jax-ws and OSB12c

Tags: java, web, service, jax-ws, osb

I need to create an async web service using jax-ws and I need configure it in a Oracle Service Bus 12c.
will you have some tutorials that explain step by step how to achieve it?
What are the best practices?

Comment: What should be the role of Oracle Service Bus in your scenario? Do you want to initiate the asynchronous Java service with an OSB service?

Comment: I want the OSB as a proxy, redirect the requests and responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use Oracle Service Bus as an intermediate layer for an asynchronous backend service, you need to create two synchronous proxy services:

- First for sending the request to the service and providing the synchronous reponse back to consumer.
- Second for sending the asynchronous response to the original consumer.
  Service Bus does not support asynchronous (long-running) services. The drawback of this solution is that these two services are completely separate.

I would prefer using BPEL for this scenario (which is also part of SOA Suite), if possible. You can create an asynchronous BPEL process which will cover the whole asynchronous communication by a single SOA composite. You can match the request and asynchronous response and easily indicate which requests got their responses. You can also utilize WS-Addressing.